# Milnor's isotopy invariant using spectral sequence?

Tags: knot-theory, gt.geometric-topology, open-problems

I'm reading stalling's article "the augmented ideal in group ring" in Ann. Math. Studies 84(R. H. Fox memorial volume) 
In his final remark, he says that Milnor's link invariant could be interpreted by using Spectral sequence.(see Milnor, Isotopy of links, Algebraic geometry and topology, Princeton press)

Are there anybody who knows about further advances in this story??

Comment: I added the open-problem tag. In his remark, Stallings suggests that the $\bar\mu$-invariants might be interpreted using the *specific* spectral sequence devised in that same paper by Stallings. I'm not aware of any reference about this. A relevant discussion is on page xiv in the introduction to a recent book by Roman Mikhailov and I.B.S. Passi.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you read the Wikipedia page on Massey products?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Massey_product

It mentions Massey products are differentials in the Atiyah-Hirzebruch spectral sequence for a K-theory with local coefficients.  The Atiyah-Hirzebruch spectral sequence is to a (co)homology theory what cellular (co)homology is for standard singular (co)homology.